# CakePHP 2.0 Installation Error, How can I fix it

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I tried to install and configure cakephp 2.0 on my local machine (wamp server), after I use the cake bake command and created a package in www folder, I tried to open in the local host but it shows the following error.

```
( ! ) Warning: include(Cake\bootstrap.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\cakecms\webroot\index.php on line 79
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  363016  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0011  387992  require( 'D:\wamp\www\cakecms\webroot\index.php' )  ..\index.php:17

( ! ) Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Cake\bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\wamp\www\lib;.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\cakecms\webroot\index.php on line 79
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  363016  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0011  387992  require( 'D:\wamp\www\cakecms\webroot\index.php' )  ..\index.php:17

( ! ) Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your \cake core directory and your \vendors root directory. in D:\wamp\www\cakecms\webroot\index.php on line 88
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  363016  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0011  387992  require( 'D:\wamp\www\cakecms\webroot\index.php' )  ..\index.php:17
3   0.0016  388856  trigger_error ( )   ..\index.php:88
```

can anyone give me an idea to overcome this error.

Comment: Do you check the mod_rewrite rules / .htaccess´s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the errors and what you're saying it sounds like you might not have installed Cake correctly.  This sentence is what I'm referring to: "after I use the cake bake command and created a package in www folder,"

To install a trial Cake project try this:

1. Make an empty directory in your Wamp document root
2. Extract the Cake distribution zip into that directory
3. Edit core.php and database.php to suit
4. Try view the directory in your browser
5. Now run Cake Bake
6. View the project again

The errors you're getting don't look like mod-rewrite issues.

Comment: Thank you so much Andy, It worked for me. you are awesome a am so happy.

Comment: Thanks :)  Welcome to the Cake world... you won't be sorry for learning this awesome framework

Comment: thank you, you are the one who helped me to enter to the Cake World